# vertical-align: middle for Fullcalendar day-number for responsive web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I added `vertical-align: middle` for all td with day number:

```
#calendar td {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

but this don't work for responsive web page for first column:[image]
How I can fix it?

I try added margin-top in % and em, its work for tablet, bot don't work on PC browser.

UPDATE: added code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8ctRu/

**HTML**

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#calendar td {
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.fc {
    text-align: center !important;
}

.fc td {
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
    },
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
        var now = new Date();

        if (date.setHours(0,0,0,0) > now.setHours(0,0,0,0)){
            $(this).toggleClass("blackAndWhite");
        } else {
            $(tempVar).css({
                'background-color':'white',
                'color' : '#000'
            });
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: please post the HTML code.

Comment: added code: http://jsfiddle.net/8ctRu/

Comment: This is a JavaScript problem.  If you look at the div inside the td, a min-height is being applied via JS.  This is preventing vertical-align from working the way you expected.

Comment: @Gene: Sorry the previous version of my answer had an error. I must have wrote that `delay` part half asleep. Check the updated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vertical-align: middle;` is not doing its job because the `div` inside the `td` is being set a `min-height` by the JavaScript.

Add `line-height` (equal to the computed `min-height`) to the `div` along with the `min-height` and the content will get aligned properly.

You can do it using the below code.

```
function setLineHeight() {
    var body = $(document).find('tbody');
    var bodyRows = body.find('tr');
    var bodyFirstCells = bodyRows.find('td:first-child');
    var cell;
    bodyFirstCells.each(function (i, _cell) {
        if (i < 7) {
            cell = $(_cell);
            var minHeight = cell.find('> div').css('min-height'); /* get computed min-height value */
            cell.find('> div').css(
                'line-height',
            minHeight); /* set the obtained min-height as line-height */
        }
    });

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(setLineHeight, 1000);
});
$(window).resize(function () {
    setTimeout(setLineHeight, 1000); /* to make sure that the plugin calculates the min-height before calling our function */
});
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ctRu/5/) | [**Full Screen Result**](http://jsfiddle.net/8ctRu/5/embedded/result/)

**Note:** Even better option would be to create a custom version of the plugin and set the `line-height` from within it.

Comment: The min-height is dynamically adjusted as the browser resizes.  For me, the cells are 57px tall.

Comment: @cinnamon: Yup mate, just now noticed it. The rule can be assigned to the `fc-first` class, just need to work out the percentages.

Comment: Actually not even `fc-first` because the Day header also seems to be using it.

Comment: @cimmanon: I have updated my answer mate. I checked and it works upon resizing the window also.

Comment: @Gene: Yea, right. Just noticed that. This can be modified to work after changing month also, but it seems like we are modifying too much of the original plugin. Do you still want to do it? If yes, I can try helping.

Comment: @Gene: As I mentioned in previous comment, we can fix that issue like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8ctRu/6/embedded/result/).

Comment: @Harry Yes, We can  modified original plugin. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Gene: Did you manage to have a look at the updated fiddle I have posted in the previous comment?

Comment: @Gene: Refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ctRu/7/). I have updated the plugin code and have linked it under external resources (only the *.min.js). If you use this, we wouldn't need to write the extra code provided in the previous fiddle. However, if you have a strong business case for this, write to the owner and get it updated ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39188/discussion-between-gene-and-harry)

Answer (score 1):

This will center the day vertically without JS. Not sure what it'll do to the events though.

Added to your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8ctRu/10/

```
.fc-day:first-child > div:first-child {
    position: relative;
}

.fc-day:first-child > div:first-child .fc-day-number {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With just CSS

```
.fc-content-skeleton>table{
    margin-top: 4%;
}
.fc-content-skeleton>table>thead>tr>td{
    text-align: center;
}
.fc-ltr .fc-basic-view .fc-day-top .fc-day-number{
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Really thanks for saving me few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Just add below css for this class .fc-day-number

```
.fc-day-number { 
    float: none !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`min-height:64px` is throwing you off..

Put the `height:64px` on the container `<td>`

Answer (score -1):

You can remove the vertical align, and add `padding-top` or `margin-top`

Comment: What is wrong with `vertical-align`? Why should the approach be changed especially when the other columns seem to be fine?

Comment: There is not enough information to to tell why vertical align is not working. I'm suggesting another option to try (notice I said "CAN"). If he leaves vertical align and trys adding padding or margin top, I'm assuming that the left column will be centered and the rest will be near the bottom

Comment: Well then that should be a suggestion/comment in my opinion.

Comment: I try add padding-top or margin-top bot this don't work for all devices (tablets, desktop)

Comment: Your opinion doesn't seem relevant to this topic

Comment: If you can't actually answer the question (due to missing code), then it's better not to post an answer.

Comment: @SethMcClaine: When you post your answer on a public forum, you make it available for comments. If you can't take it, don't bother posting it. Or you can choose to safely ignore any comment.

Comment: It is a resolution, are you saying that resolution would never work @cimmanon?

Comment: @Harry, didn't say I can't take it, if you can read it say you are off topic like this whole comment thread